# Array of JCheckBoxes

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jcheckbox, itemlistener

i  am adding  around  10 check boxes in   a JFrame  , These are added  in for loop being iterted on  Array , code goes like this

```
    JFrame f=new JFrame("hello ");
    FlowLayout fl= new FlowLayout();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(300,300);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setLayout(fl);

    for (int i=0 ; i<10; i++)
    {

        b[i]=new JCheckBox();
        b[i].setVisible(true);
        b[i].addItemListener(this);
        f.add(b[i]);

    }  /// and so on .
```

My Question is  when i  implement ItemListener  will i have to    access each of the CheckBox like This
    if(b[1].isSelected())   ,       if(b[2].isSelected())  or  there is anyother technique can be used  like a loop or something like This .. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Two thoughts come to mind. You can use the loop idea, or you can maintain a list of those checkboxes that are selected by adding/removing the event source when the item listener is triggered

Comment: If you are going to have a lot of JCheckBoxes, consider instead using a JTable holding a column of Booleans (which render as checkboxes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ItemListener` will be invoked with an instance of `ItemEvent`. This event has a source (`EventObject#getSource()`), which will be the component which triggered the event, e.g. your `JCheckBox`.

Comment: so it means if i use 100 jcheckBoxes Jbuttons etc  There is going to be 100 if , else  or switch  Conditions that will  be too heavy code , And i have done that  , i wanted something like   iterating  a loop or some similar solution that gets  the  seleted item itself instead of going for  b[1] , b[2]  etc   ..

Comment: @Sikander @sarcans method allows for you to gain access to the Object/CheckBox through `EventObject#getSource()` you will have to explictly cast is to a `JCheckBox` though like: `JCheckBox cb=(JCheckBox)e.getSource();` and then you can simply `cb.isSelected()` or whatever

Comment: i dont need to cast  if i do it like this  Object  obj=e.getsource(); , but my question if i  iterate a loop and instead of accessing each one separate  is it possible to   access them same way  as they are added ...  They are added in loop and [i] assigns them values , now  can we access required one  using    arrays of loops   if  i m not wrong ?

Comment: Of course you can iterate over your array in a for-loop, or rather a for-each loop. `for (JCheckBox c : b) if (c.isSelected()) ...`. Question is why you'd want to do that.

Comment: @Sikander: **you** should be the one writing the code. We'll be more than glad to help you, but please don't ask others to do your homework or write your code for you. That's your responsibility. -1 vote for your comment, to be removed when/if you retract this.

Comment: Sorry i will,   Ok plz guide me about it

Answer (score 1):

> so it means if i use 100 jcheckBoxes Jbuttons etc There is going to be
>   100 if , else or switch Conditions that will be too heavy code , And i
>   have done that , i wanted something like iterating a loop or some
>   similar solution that gets the seleted item itself instead of going
>   for b[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10385302/714968) , b[2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setName%28java.lang.String%29) etc

you can

- [putClientProperty (example about JButton, the same for JCheckBox and ItemListener)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10385302/714968)
- [setName(String);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setName%28java.lang.String%29)
- [setActionCommand(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setActionCommand%28java.lang.String%29)
- [hold reference (example about JButton, the same for JCheckBox and ItemListener)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9007348/714968)