# Using ActionListener to swap two icons in a grid

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, awt, actionlistener, chess

I'm trying to move a piece from one square in a grid to another by clicking first on the piece and then clicking on the square to move it too.

How can I save the location of the first icon, and then swap it with the second?

At the moment I'm looking at this code which simply moves the piece one square left:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  
{
for ( x=0; x<8; x++)
        for( y=0; y<8; y++) {
        if(e.getSource() == board[x][y])
        ((ChessSquare)e.getSource()).swap(board[x][y-1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Store a flag indicating whether this is a 'drag' or 'drop'<sup>1</sup>.
- If 'drag' store the original co-ordinates and change the flag to 'drop'.
- If 'drop' read the co-ordinates of the source, use them as you will and set the flag back to 'drag'.

---

1. By that I mean something like declaring a `boolean drag` and setting it `true`/`false` as needed.

> ..best place to store the coordinates?

I'd use 2 `int` attributes, though if you wanted to misuse a `Dimension` object, just one could store both x & y co-ords.

..No, scrap that.  Using the client properties as indicated by mKorbel seems a lot more 'neat'.

Comment: Where would be the best place to store the coordinates?

Comment: probably [putClientProperty](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10385302/714968) is easiest of the ways, sure ...., maybe not

Comment: @mKorbel  Huh, ..neat!  The things in the docs I've missed.  :)

Answer (score 0):

- We'll need a Boolean flag which will keep track of 'click'
- if flag = false it's first click otherwise it's second click (this is
  where we'll perform swap).

  ```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  
  {
      int xPos1,xPos2,yPos1,yPos2;
      if(!flag)
      {
        for ( x=0; x<8; x++)
        {
            for( y=0; y<8; y++) 
            {
              if(e.getSource() == board[x][y])
              {
                xPos1 = x; // Source icon cordinates.
                yPos2 = y;
                break;
              }
            }
        }
        flag = true;
      }
      else
      {
        for ( x=0; x<8; x++)
        {
          for( y=0; y<8; y++) 
          {
            if(e.getSource() == board[x][y])
            {
              xPos2 = x;  // Target icon cordinates.
              yPos2 = y;
              break;
            }
          }
        }

        // Swapping code add your version of this swapping code here.
        // Swap source with target.
        Icon temp = board[xPos1][yPos1]
        board[xPos1][yPos1] = board[xPos2][yPos2];
        board[xPos2][yPos2] = temp;          
        // ----------------- End Swap----------------  

        flag = false; // ready for next swap operation.
    }
  ```

  }

Comment: should very complicated, see code in my comment to another question here,