# 2D array JButtons not working for get() methods?

Tags: java, swing, get, jbutton, swap

i was been trying to do a chess game and got stuck on swaping two piecess

this is my ChessSquare class

```
   public class ChessSquare extends JButton 



{ 




public int Yposition;
public int Xposition;
private String Type;
public ChessSquare( Icon s, int y , int x , String piece )

{
 super(s);

 Yposition = y;
 Xposition = x;
 Type = piece ;
}         

public int getXposition()
 {
   return this.Xposition;
 }  


    public int getYposition()
 {
   return this.Xposition;
 }  


    public String getType()
   {
      return "";
   }

 }
```

then i add this to the ChessBoard class, using the ChessSquare class as 2D array

```
     public class ChessBoard extends JFrame implements ActionListener
  {
     String type;
     ChessSquare[][] s = new ChessSquare[8][8];
     int xPos1,xPos2,yPos1,yPos2,i,j;
     JPanel panel;


    ........


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
       Boolean flag = false ;

         if(!flag)
  {
     xPos1 = s.getYposition();
     yPos1 = s.getXposition();

     flag = true;
   }
     else
   {

    xPos2 = s.getYposition();
    yPos2 = s.getXposition();


    s[xPos1][yPos1] = s[xPos2][yPos2];
    s[xPos2][yPos2] = s[xPos1][yPos1];
    flag = false;


 }


 }

 }
```

trying to swap two pieces...but its not working? please help...
[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methods `getXposition` and `getYposition` are instance methods of your custom `ChessSquare` class, rather than your `ChessSquare` *array*. To access the methods you would have to reference the elements in your `2D` array, e.g.:

```
xPos1 = s[0][0].getYposition();
yPos1 = s[0][0].getXposition();
```

Comment: why complicating the simple things, don't do that, not never as an answer :-), its about prepare all things that you needed before, intialize on ....,  [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10385302/714968) and  [here (and see EventHandler == my love)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9007348/714968)
, and used LayoutManager can returns coordinates too (in most cases JComponent can be swapable in this array, but (the same) there no reason do it that in most cases == wrong concept)